# Sound of notifications working but media of apps not

Tags: notifications, audio, media-player

1 → All volumes are maxed out
2 → My device has "Do Not Disturb" mode disabled
3 → My device has "Battery Saver" mode disabled

My notifications work perfectly sound, but when I try to play any kind of media in any app, no sound comes out on my device.

Is there anything that can be done in such cases to try to resolve the issue? Any option in developer mode, anyway...

Here are his specs:

[image]

Comment: If the phone has a headphone socket make sure it is clean. Otherwise the phone may detect a non-existent headphone and thus redirect all sound to the headphone socket.

Comment: Can this happen even though the device does not show the icon of a connected headset @Robert?

Comment: Are you sure that your phone shows such an icon? (I have not sees such an icon on mine). I just noticed that your screen shot shows a crossed-out speaker icon next to the Wifi icon. Are you sure audio is enabled in quick settings (switch between Sound -> Vibrate -> Mute -> Sound)?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure @Robert (I'll even crop that part of the image to avoid confusion.). I've turned off ringtone because I use it that way by default, but as for the media being active, I'm totally and absolutely sure. The problem is actually linked to something in the headphone jack. Is there any way to check if there is a device connected to the input to check?

Comment: When I put it in any mode, everything works perfectly for notifications and the like. The problem is only in the application media.